# Migration from RestTemplate to Java default HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpclient, resttemplate

We've been using RestTemplate in our Spring Boot application in order to send rest requests to multiple dependencies. We use different timeouts for each dependencies and for this reason, we build a single rest template for each client and put all RestTemplates into an immutable map and then later use it while sending the requests. We also have a config service integration and if any timeout value changes in the config, we basically replace existing RestTemplate.

My question is, are there any differences between using same Java HttpClient or creating a new HttpClient with each request? Basically is it worth to keep HttpClient singleton per dependency or build a new one on the fly?

We’ve never tried default HttpClient.